# UPDATE / EDIT SQL Database From Console C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, console

I'm trying to update a value in the primary key column in a sql database via console C#.
I have searched the Internet for a few hours, but still cant work out why my database wont update and to make things worse I am not getting any errors to work with.

```
 static void editMONDAY()
    {
        SQLCONN.Open();
        var TIME = DateTime.Now;
        SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.mondayTable", SQLCONN);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd0.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int n = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(" [" + reader.GetValue(n).ToString() + " TIMES]     [TEACHER / CLASSROOM]      MONDAY " + TIME.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");

            for (int i = 1; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i +" - " + reader.GetName(i) + "      " + reader.GetValue(i));
            }
        }

        SQLCONN.Close(); //stop memory leaks??? wait and see!
        Console.WriteLine("Which group would you like to edit?");
        string Group = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the groups new name or same name is nothing is to change");
        string newGroup = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Which classtime would you like to edit?");
        string Class = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the new teacher and classroom number");
        string newClass = Console.ReadLine(); 
        //SQLCONN.Open();
        //update ID (SAT)
        using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("UPDATE mondayTable SET SAT=@SAT where SAT=@"+Group, SQLCONN))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@"+Group, newGroup);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        menu();
```

UPDATE: Here is the Table that I am hoping to update.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mondayTable] (
[SAT]         VARCHAR(50)           NOT NULL,
[09:00-09.40] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[10:10-10:50] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[11.00-11:40] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[11:50-12:30] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[12:40-13:20] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[13:30-14:10] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[14:20-15:00] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[15:10-15:50] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[16:00-16:40] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[16:50-17:30] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[17:40-18:20] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[18:30-19:10] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[19:20-20:00] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SAT] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? if the ID is a primary key autoincrement you won't be allowed to modify it, doesn't have anything to do with C#

Comment: No errors, It just continue as if it was successful, Im not using numbers for the primary key.

Comment: What is the connectionstring?

Comment: the connection is ok, because I can read everything from the table. However if it does make any differences, i set up the database within visual studio and not sql server management, the connection string is as follows `public static string myMONDAYConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= c:\users\werdna\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cSharp\ConsoleApp1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";`

Comment: You're not opening the connection for the second command, which makes me believe this isn't your actual code or you are just eating the exceptions and are unaware of it

Comment: even with that open, it still doesnt update, I commented it out, to see if i could get an error, however, because Im using the `sqlcommand` i believe it is opening the connection for me

Comment: where are you calling `editMONDAY()`?

Comment: The second query requires two parameters (@SAT and @Group) but you add just one. This should fail with an exception. If you don't see it then you have some try/catch that hides the problem?

Comment: Im calling `editMONDAY()` another static void eg "Select a day you wish to edit'

Comment: @Steve I have posted the table Im hoping to edit, I know that when you are inserting a new value that you have to add each column with a parameter, in otder to update, will i have to add each column?

Comment: I am telling you that the query as is written now requires two parameters @SAT and @+Group but the AddWithValue has just @+Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update query requires two parameters @SAT and @Group but you supply just one.
I am not certain what value you want to set for the parameter SAT.

However, if you want to change the old value of SAT (Group) with a newGroup then this is how you should add it.

```
// Do not close before or reopen here
SQLCONN.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd =
    new SqlCommand("UPDATE mondayTable SET SAT=@SAT where SAT=@"+Group, SQLCONN))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SAT", newGroup);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@"+Group, Group);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: ohhhh I see, so each time you have an @ symbol, you are required to an a parameter for each of them? thank you for helping me understand, I was thinking that my query was the problem.

Comment: Yes each @ introduces a parameter placeholder in the query. Then the command object should have a matching parameter in its collection. But really you don't see any exception here? Do you have a try/catch at upper level that catch and hides the error?

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge, yeah, the only time there is a try statement is at the very start when it tests to see if there is a connection, just quickly where you say that @ introduces a parameter where it has "@Sat",newGroup" why do you have to have newGroup? like what happens if the newGroup isnt on the table?

Comment: I assume that SAT is the column where you keep the current group name. And according to your WriteLines you want to change the Group name to something else. So you search for the old group name and change it to newgroup name.

Comment: I see I see said the blind man! Thanks Steve, I always enjoy reading your answers that you post for people :) Thank you again!

Comment: I am honoured by your words.